# Need help simplifying a boolean expression using algebraic theorems/postulates only

Tags: boolean-algebra

Suppose I have this boolean expression:

W'XYZ + WX'YZ + WXY'Z + WXYZ' + WXYZ

How would I go about simplifying this without using a K-map? Using K-map, the simplified form is XYZ + WXY + WXZ + WYZ. I read about the redundancy theorem somewhere, would rather not use that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good law for you to use:

**Adjacency**

$PQ +PQ'=P$

It's called Adjacency because if you *were* to put it on a K-map, the two terms in the left hand side would pick out cells that are adjacent in the K-Map and that can be combined into one larger group of cells ... hence the much simpler expression.

Comment: I'm guessing saying W'XYZ + WXYZ = XYZ is an example of this law in action? I'm clueless with regards to simplifying the other three terms though, since we lose the WXYZ after this first step.

Comment: @SanchitBatra yes, it is ... and you can always copy terms using $P=P+P$ so you don't 'lose' them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @SanchitBatra Glad I could help! :)